# How to get name of ProcessInstanceStep in apex?

Tags: apex, approval-process

I have to get the name of ProcessInstanceStep with apex. In my case it is Approval Request Submitted. There is no the name field in ProcessInstanceStep object, but I think it is possible to get it via some lookups.
Thanks
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you need to get the step name of a given `ProcessInstanceStep` you may have to run a separate query against [`ProcessInstanceNode`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ProcessInstanceNode.htm) using the `ProcessInstanceId`, on the field `ProcessNodeName` it will have the step name.

E.g.

```
SELECT Id, ProcessNodeName
FROM ProcessInstanceNode
WHERE
  ProcessInstanceId = '<ProcessInstanceId From ProcessInstanceStep>'
```

Note: there lookups indirectly but on the parent object [`ProcessInstance`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ProcessInstance.htm) (e.g. `Nodes` references `ProcessInstanceNode` & `Steps` references `ProcessInstanceStep`)